# How to add a row dynamically in a bootstrap table based on the response from API?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="binding-table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>UID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In my main.js file:

```
var response = '[{"rank":"ss9", "content":"Alon", "UID":"5" }]';
/* response += ',{"rank":"6","content":"Tala","UID":"6"}]'; */
response = $.parseJSON(response);

$(function () {
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(item.rank),
            $('<td>').text(item.content),
            $('<td>').text(item.UID)).appendTo('#binding-table');

    });
});
```

I have the response that is returned from API. I am parsing the response and adding the rows dynamically based on the response. In my case, I am making the mistake inside  tag. Can someone help me where my mistake is?

Comment: Missing a double-quote? `id="binding-table>`

Answer (score 2):

Aside the fact that you are missing a double-quote on table id, I think you have to "cache" the reference for the tbody element, so you don't have use the selector for every loop, lets say, for a larger json.

Also just like @Enter Strandman sugested to you, for this kind of situation, it is better to use [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/)

```js
var response = '[{"rank":"ss9", "content":"Alon", "UID":"5" },{"rank":"6","content":"Tala","UID":"6"}]';
response = $.parseJSON(response);

$(function () {
    var tbody = $('#table_body');
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(item.rank),
            $('<td>').text(item.content),
            $('<td>').text(item.UID)).appendTo(tbody);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed" id="binding-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>UID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="table_body">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://datatables.net/, I would've commented this but it wouldn't let me. Also, try writing a script to add all the pieces of data to the table and feed the data items in as a parameter. I also recommend looking into AJAX.